# Unity - Object reference is set in editor but isn't set in game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a Unity project in which the door is set to the GameObject "Door". It is fine and set in the editor (i.e. when I'm not playing it), but as soon as I hit play, it turns to "None (GameObject)". My script uses the Rigidbody component of the door, but I access that through the script. Do I need to reference the Rigidbody component instead?

Why is it doing this?

```
using UnityEngine;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject door;

    void Start ()
    {
        door = GameObject.Find("Door1");
    }

    public void NextLevel () {
        Debug.Log("open");
        door.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(0, 0, 500);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be the [lifecycle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html) functions of the script overriding the reference. Try to attach the script in your question, if you couldn’t, check the [`Awake`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Awake.html), [`Start`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html), [`Update`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html) or [`FixedUpdate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html) functions, if it is set back to `null` by typo.

Comment: Yeah, the script is overriding the reference. I see the problem now. Thanks!

Comment: Now I get to see your code, please note that 'GetComponent()' is a very slow process, assuming that your the 'rigidbody' of the 'door' won't change during the gameplay, it should be placed in 'Start()'.

Comment: So I should make a variable referencing the rigidbody component and apply a force to that instead?

Comment: yes. Make a 'private Rigidbody doorRB' field in the class, then, in 'Start()', 'doorRB = door.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();'

Comment: Thanks, that will help. Also, do you have any thoughts on this problem I have? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52017955/rigidbodies-moving-without-input-when-two-levels-are-connected

Comment: I have had a look in that before, but it's impossible to debug without seeing the compile results.

Comment: The compile results? What's that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178803/discussion-between-boris-li-and-william-jones).