# Rigidbodies moving without input when two levels are connected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make to make a game in Unity where you collide with the button to open the door and access the next level. When the two levels are disconnected, like in the first picture, it functions perfectly and the player and doors do not move until a force is applied to them.

[image: Disconnected levels]
But, if I change it so that the two levels are joined together, like the second picture, the player and doors begin to slowly move, which is proving to be quite problematic for my game.

[image: Connected levels]

I don't think this has anything to do with my scripts, I think this is just to do with Unity.

I don't understand why this is happening only when the levels are connected, so if anyone has any ideas or fixes, I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it has something to do with colliders, if any are attached to connecting parts of the levels. You can try to shorten them a bit on one or both sides and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

[Touching](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionStay.html) [colliders](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.html) may results in unexpected forces applied.